# No SslStream in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: ssl, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET 5 and I have question is there `SslStream` class in `System.Security` namespace?

I do have `SslPolicyErrors` and `SslProtocols` enums and I do have `NetworkStream`. I can extract `NetwokrStream` from `TcpClient`, but I do not know how to use it as SSL (there was `SslStream` object waaaay back in beta3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to reference the `System.Net.Security` package, as it's where `SslStream` for .NET Core lives: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Security/4.0.0-beta-23516.

Comment: I am referencing using System.Net.Security; and I do not have access to this object (dnxcore "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1") - i need to add package you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, add the `System.Net.Security` package under frameworks\dnxcore50\dependencies.

Comment: thanks a million - strange that's not included out of the box